# hibernate not calling setReadOnly(true) on connection

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, master-slave

I'm trying to set up my spring / hibernate project to work with master/slave database setup.

Transactions seem to work in spring (for example when I try to hibernateTemplate.merge() within a method annotated as @Transactional(readOnly=true) I get an exception).  But hibernate does not use the slave database within methods annotated.

@Transactional(readOnly=true).

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/proust"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Then I annotate the manager class or DAO class with:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

... and some methods with

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
```

I expect some methods in the class to be executed against the master, and some against the slave, but they all get executed against the master.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not switch the JDBC connection to the R/O mode with regard to the `@Transactional` annotation, it only prevents flushing of changes.